# Convert Vue.JS project to Nuxt.JS project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I want to create Nuxt.JS project from Vue.JS project.

> Vue.js Project

You can see the full Vue.JS project [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-conversational-form-example?file=myForm.js). This project uses npm package [vue-conversational-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-conversational-form) which can help turn web forms into conversations using Vue.js.

Project has 3 files:

1. **index.html**
2. **index.js**
3. **myForm.js**

**Code of:** `index.html`

```
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 90%;
    width: 96%;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
</style>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Code of:** `index.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import myForm from './myForm';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<myForm />',
  components: {
    myForm
  }
})
```

**Code of:** `myForm.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { ConversationalForm } from 'conversational-form';

export default Vue.component('MyForm', {
  template: '<div class="myForm"></div>',
  styles: [`
    .myForm {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  `],
  methods: {
    setupForm: function () {
      const formFields = [
        {
          'tag': 'input',
          'type': 'text',
          'name': 'firstname',
          'cf-questions': 'What is your firstname?'
        },
        {
          'tag': 'input',
          'type': 'text',
          'name': 'lastname',
          'cf-questions': 'What is your lastname?'
        }
      ];

      this.cf = ConversationalForm.startTheConversation({
        options: {
          submitCallback: this.submitCallback,
          preventAutoFocus: true,
        },
        tags: formFields
      });
      this.$el.appendChild(this.cf.el);
    },
    submitCallback: function () {
      var formDataSerialized = this.cf.getFormData(true);
      console.log("Formdata, obj:", formDataSerialized);
      this.cf.addRobotChatResponse("You are done. Check the dev console for form data output.")
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.setupForm()
  },
});
```

> Nuxt.js Project

Now here you can see my tried to convert this Vue.Js project to Nuxt.js project from [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/codesandbox-nuxt-conversational-form-ssxnf).

Project has 2 files:

1. **index.vue** (page)
2. **MyForm.vue** (component)

**Code of:** `index.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <MyForm></MyForm>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyForm from '~/components/MyForm.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    MyForm
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  html, body {
    height: 90%;
    width: 96%;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
</style>
```

**Code of:** `MyForm.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="myForm"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.setupForm()
  },
  methods: {
    setupForm() {
      const formFields = [
        {
          'tag': 'input',
          'type': 'text',
          'name': 'firstname',
          'cf-questions': 'What is your firstname?'
        },
        {
          'tag': 'input',
          'type': 'text',
          'name': 'lastname',
          'cf-questions': 'What is your lastname?'
        }
      ];

      const { ConversationalForm } = require('conversational-form');

      this.cf = ConversationalForm.startTheConversation({
        options: {
          submitCallback: this.submitCallback,
          preventAutoFocus: true,
        },
        tags: formFields
      });
      this.$el.appendChild(this.cf.el);
    },
    submitCallback() {
      var formDataSerialized = this.cf.getFormData(true);
      console.log("Formdata, obj:", formDataSerialized);
      this.cf.addRobotChatResponse("You are done. Check the dev console for form data output.")
    }
  } 
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  .myForm {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

I do not get any errors when I run the Nuxt.JS project, but in a browser window, it does not display the same result as the original Vue.JS project.

Why am I getting errors on code convertation process? Thanks!

Comment: what is different in projects?

Comment: Different only one project in two another frameworks. Work in Vue.Js and not work in Nuxt.Js. If I correct doing in Nuxt.Js then project must work but in my case not work. I think what I do something error on convertation process and can't found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap the `.myForm` in `~/components/MyForm.vue` with an extra div. Here's an example https://codesandbox.io/embed/codesandbox-nuxt-conversational-form-oh9y4

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="myForm"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```