# Converting existing vue project to nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to convert existing vuejs project to nuxt.js project. For this I have created nuxt.js project and moved moved files to nuxt project. I had copied scr/view/layout and paste into layouts folder, vuex store files into store folder. Inside Layouts.vue changed this tag  to this . Updated nuxt.config.js file accordingly added styles, modules and plugins. updated all broken paths.

But when we try to npm run dev it gave errors.

> Error example

```
ERROR in ./assets/js/components/cookie.js
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
ERROR in ./assets/js/components/cookie.js
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
D:\VueJs-Projects\nuxtapp\assets\js\components\cookie.js
  9:29  error  Unnecessary escape character: \.  no-useless-escape
  9:37  error  Unnecessary escape character: \(  no-useless-escape
  9:39  error  Unnecessary escape character: \)  no-useless-escape
  9:41  error  Unnecessary escape character: \[  no-useless-escape
  9:47  error  Unnecessary escape character: \/  no-useless-escape
  9:49  error  Unnecessary escape character: \+  no-useless-escape
✖ 6 problems (6 errors, 0 warnings)
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCdLe.jpg
```

[You can see detail of errors here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08gFk.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Vue.JS project to Nuxt.JS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58437066/convert-vue-js-project-to-nuxt-js-project)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you’ve chosen to use ESLint in the nuxt app, and the code from your existing app is triggering the ‘no-useless-escape’ error.

If you know the line the error is occurring at (the output gives you this information; looks like line 9 in cookie.js in the components folder is the issue) you can wrap that code inside the following:

```
/* eslint-disable no-useless-escape */
... 
some code
...
/* eslint-enable no-useless-escape */
```

However I’d recommend choosing the same linter that you used for your Vue app, otherwise you may encounter other similar errors.

Comment: We are using same versions, still facing issues

Comment: Can you share your package.json?